# Selected items are no longer marked as selected after searching for a specific item

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

The app loads recipes from an API and outputs them to a GridView.builder.

The user must select at least 3 recipes in order to be able to continue processing the next step.

Everything works up to this point. However, if the user searches for a specific recipe, the list will be reloaded but the recipes that have already been selected will no longer be marked as selected.

After clicking "Continue", all selected recipes are displayed in a modal bottom sheet as expected.

The only problem is that the visual marker (Check icon) is lost as soon as the user uses the search.

The following code visualizes whether a recipe has been selected:

```
if (_selected.contains(recipe))
  Positioned(
    top: 8,
    right: 8,
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.deepPurple,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(
          width: 1,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      child: const Icon(
        Icons.check,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 18,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

It seems as if after the search the condition `if(_selected.contains(recipe))` no longer works.

Here is the complete code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _search = TextEditingController();
  List<dynamic> _recipes = [];
  List<dynamic> _selected = [];
  bool isLoading = false;

  Dio dio = Dio(
    BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: 'https://dummyjson.com',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    ),
  );

  Future<void> getRecipes() async {
    Response response;

    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      if (_search.text.isEmpty) {
        response = await dio.get('/recipes');
      } else {
        response = await dio.get('/recipes/search', queryParameters: {
          'q': _search.text,
        });
      }

      setState(() {
        _recipes = response.data['recipes'];
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      isLoading = false;
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }

  void showSelected() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTextStyle(
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          child: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: ListView.separated(
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: _selected.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Map recipe = _selected[index];

                      return ListTile(
                        leading: AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 1,
                          child: Image.network(recipe['image']),
                        ),
                        title: Text(
                          recipe['name'],
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getRecipes();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _search.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget searchIcon = GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => setState(() {
        _search.clear();
        getRecipes();
      }),
      child: Icon(_search.text.isEmpty ? Icons.search : Icons.close),
    );

    if (isLoading) {
      searchIcon = const UnconstrainedBox(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 3),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Choose at least 3 recipes'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _selected.length < 3 ? null : showSelected,
          child: Text('Continue (${_selected.length.toString()})'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _search,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search',
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                suffixIcon: searchIcon,
              ),
              onTapOutside: (PointerDownEvent event) {
                FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
              },
              onChanged: (String value) async {
                getRecipes();
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 16,
                right: 16,
                bottom: 16,
              ),
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                childAspectRatio: 0.65,
              ),
              itemCount: _recipes.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Map recipe = _recipes[index];

                return GestureDetector(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                _selected.contains(recipe) ? 5 : 0),
                            color: Colors.deepPurple,
                            child: AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 1,
                              child: Image.network(recipe['image']),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Text(
                              recipe['name'],
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: _selected.contains(recipe)
                                      ? Colors.deepPurple
                                      : null),
                              maxLines: 2,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      if (_selected.contains(recipe))
                        Positioned(
                          top: 8,
                          right: 8,
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.deepPurple,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              border: Border.all(
                                width: 1,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: const Icon(
                              Icons.check,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                    ],
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    if (_selected.contains(recipe)) {
                      setState(() => _selected.remove(recipe));
                    } else {
                      setState(() => _selected.add(recipe));
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update**

I have uploaded the complete source code here => https://filebin.net/qrh5xajhhuldv4z7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current `recipe` object is a different instance to the existing recipe element inside the `_selected` list, even if the content is the same. The [`contains`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html) method relies on [operator==](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.4/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) to check for equality, so it won't work as expected.

You can verify by printing their hash codes:

```
if (_selected.length == 1) {
  print(recipe.hashCode);
  print(_selected.first.hashCode);
}
```

The hash codes will be different.

---

One way to make the check success is to change `_selected.contains(recipe)` to

```dart
_selected.any((item) => item['id'] == recipe['id'])
```

You also need to change how you remove items from the list by replacing `_selected.remove(recipe)` to

```dart
_selected.removeWhere((item) => item['id'] == recipe['id'])
```

---

**Recommendation:**

In Dart, it is common to convert json result to a model rather than using it directly as a map. You can see this guide from the official Flutter documentation: [Serializing JSON inside model classes](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/serialization/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes).

Other option is to use packages such as [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) or [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed).

Comment: When I read your answer, that of course makes sense.

Your solution worked.

Thank you for that.

Regarding your recommendation: In the original, the recipes are declared as models. I tried to keep the code for this example as small as possible and therefore threw out the Model class.